# Does QTabletEvent works only with wacom driver?

Tags: qt, wacom

There is n-trig and synaptic now (dell venue pro) except wacom. In docs about QtabletEvent I found nothing about support any of these technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Well since there's a line in Qt documentation:

> Tablet Events are generated from a Wacom tablet.

So I believe the answer is yes. I think the reason is because it's hard to support any other drivers in cross-platform fashion currently.